# How to import Opera Mobile 9 bookmarks into Opera 10 Mobile Beta 3

Tags: opera, windows-mobile

On my Samsung Saga, I've been using the Opera 9 as my default browser. I just installed [Opera 10 Beta 3](http://www.opera.com/mobile/download/) and I want to import the Opera 9 bookmarks into Opera 10.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Does Opera 9 have support for Opera Link ? If so you can use it to sync your bookmarks.

Comment: No, I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=407671) is just about your topic: upgrade to 9.7 and then copy opera6.adr to Opera 10 profile